# AmazonClientException when uploading file with spring-integration-aws S3MessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration

I have configured an `S3MessageHandler` from spring-integration-aws to upload a `File` object to S3.

The upload fails with the following trace:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected: dataLength=0; expectedLength=26; includeSkipped=false; in.getClass()=class com.amazonaws.internal.ResettableInputStream; markedSupported=true; marked=0; resetSinceLastMarked=false; markCount=1; resetCount=0
>       at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.checkLength(LengthCheckInputStream.java:152)
>   ...

Looking at the source code for `S3MessageHandler`, I'm not sure how uploading a `File` would ever succeed.  The `s3MessageHandler.upload()` method does the following when I trace its execution:

- Creates a FileInputStream for the File.
- Computes the MD5 hash for the file contents, using the input stream.
- Resets the stream if it can be reset (not possible for FileInputStream).
- Sets up the S3 transfer using the input stream.  This fails because the stream is at the EOF, so the number of transferable bytes doesn't match what's in the Content-Length header.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the message handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; it's a bug; please open an [Issue in GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues) and/or a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT).

For `FileInputStream` a new one should be created, for `InputStream` payloads, we need to assert that `markSupported()` is true if MD5 consumes the stream.

Consider [Contributing a fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc) after "signing" the CLA.

**EDIT**

I opened [JIRA Issue INTEXT-225](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-225).

Comment: Haha...I opened 226.  Will close it as a duplicate.

[Issue #41](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/41) in the spring-integration-aws repo is linked to your JIRA issue now.